# How to remove this paragraph tags in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

I have added some text using WYSIWYG editor and want to show in admin side but its showing with paragraph tag

How to remove this tags

Comment: please see screenshot attached

Comment: @7ochem I want to show text after add and its is showing with p tag check screenshot

Comment: Please remove this text this This question may already have an answer here:

Comment: @Marius I have created a module using ultimate module generator and this module having a editor after saving add module.I want to show in list but in list it is showing with paragraph tag.I need editor for saving contents but in listing it is showing paragraph tag.I want to remove only this tag

Answer (score 1):

use `strip_tags` to remove html tag from a string

```
$test = strip_tags($yourVariable);
```

Refer this [**Link**](https://secure.php.net/strip_tags)

Answer (score 1):

usually find disabling it all together is the best way to go. If that's an option you can find the settings here:

**System > Configuration > Content Management > WYSIWYG Options**
select option **N**O

Comment: but I need on by default

Comment: I am not using static block

Comment: I have a module to add description

Comment: f it's only for cms pages then the <p> comes from the content of the page. Edit the page in CMS->Pages and replace the tag with a <div>.

Comment: Its come from WYSIWYG editor

Comment: use the WYSIWYG but check your HTML afterwards.default. means?